# Unity first person mouse control doesn't work properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying  to do a first person camera for the first time, and I have a little issue here.
I have 2 objects, a capsule and a camera. Camera is child of  Capsule.
i want to rotate to the sides(Y)  in the capsule, and tilt up and down in the camera( the "head"). But when i put this scripts, one in each object, I can't rotate the camera to the sides, just up and down, and I have a "shaking" movement(like when you collide with a wall).
this is my capsule code

```
    [SerializeField] private int speed = 10;


void Update()
{
    gameObject.transform.Translate
        (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")* speed * Time.deltaTime);
   
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0);

}
```

And this is my Camera Code

```
    private float angle;

void Update()
{

    angle += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(-angle, -90, 90), 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe in the camera you want to use `transform.localEulerAngles`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're setting the capsule's y-rotation directly to 
 `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` 
But `GetAxis("Mouse X")` will return a value of 0 when not moving the mouse and a value of -1 / 1 when moving the mouse to the left / right.

 What you should do instead is adding `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` to the capsule's current y-rotation like this (you also need to multiply it by time.deltaTime to make it framerate-independentd): 
`transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * time.deltaTime, 0)`

also your camera-rotation needs to be multiplied by deltaTime to make it independent from the games framerate. Just change: 
`angle += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");` 
to: 
`angle += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * time.deltaTime;`